# Elasticsearch: Limit of total fields setting when creating index

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-7

I am struggling with a new problem in ElasticSearch 7. I get the "limit of total fields" error when trying to create the index with auto map in Nest library, c#.

```
 await _elasticContext.GetClient().Indices.CreateAsync(indexName, c => c
                .Map<DocumentWrapper>(m => m.AutoMap()));
```

Question is how to integrate the `index.mapping.total_fields.limit` into the query above? Or an alternative solution, if there is one?

Thank you

Comment: Andrew, I need to speak to you about something.  Can we chat somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please find an example below

```
var response = await client.Indices.CreateAsync("my_index1", c => c
    .Settings(s => s.Setting("index.mapping.total_fields.limit", 10))
    .Map(m => m.AutoMap<Document>()));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could not work out how the s.Setting part is working.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of fields in an index. Field and object mappings, as well as field aliases count towards this limit. The default value is 1000. 
see [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/mapping.html#field-datatypes)